# Getting Element Annotation from an AnnotationMirror

Tags: java, annotations

Is there an better way to get an Element Annotation from an AnnotationMirror than this? This seems really hacky to me.

```
for (AnnotationMirror annotationMirror : element.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
    try {
        Class annotationClass = Class.forName(annotationMirror.getAnnotationType().toString());
        Annotation annotation = element.getAnnotation(annotationClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `element` come from?  Is this code intended to be part of an annotation processor?

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on what the intended output is. As it stands, the block doesn't do anything. Perhaps you require the output of a particular class?

Answer (score 6):

I think you just want:

javax.lang.model.element.Element

```
<A extends Annotation> A getAnnotation(Class<A> annotationType)
```

> Returns this element's annotation for the specified type if such an
>   annotation is present, else null. The annotation may be either
>   inherited or directly present on this element.

And supply a class explicitly (e.g., `name.class`).

It is hard to see why you would want to use `Class.forName(variable)` instead of `name.class` to explicitly name the class. If you use the forName call you don't actually know the type of annotation you are getting. You would have to follow it by an `instanceof` or something similar to check what annotation you had got, in which case you might as well have just explicitly requested that annotation type.

Comment: I'm using that method on line 4, supplying it with the class from line 3. I'm looking for a way to avoid `Class.forName()`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: it can't be done -- you have to use `Class.forName()`.

The [`javax.lang.model`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/lang/model/package-summary.html) package (and subpackages) are designed for dealing with source code (the primary use case being [annotation processors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html)).  In these cases, you typically have not yet produced binary artifacts (i.e. `.class` files) for the [`Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html)s you're dealing with, so invoking `Class.forName()` is likely to fail.

If you can give us more details about where `element` comes from or what you want to do with `annotation` once you've obtained it, we might be able to provide more guidance.  It's likely that the [`DeclaredType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html) returned by `annotationMirror.getAnnotationType()` provides access to the information you're after in a more reliable way than [`Annotation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) would.

Comment: I don't know about the OP but I found this question trying to look for sibling annotations on a method i.e. I find a class annotation with @SomeAnnotation, then iterate on the members of that class trying to find what annotations are on each member and what values are attached to them.

Comment: @SaadFarooq, are you doing this search at runtime (starting from `java.lang.Class.getAnnotations()` or similar), or inside an annotation processor?  It might make more sense for you to ask a new question, so we can address your goal separately from @MichaelPardo's.